# When to use java.util.concurrent.Semaphore's acquire() and acquireUninterruptibly() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am new to Java concurrency/multi-threading. Can somebody please explain to me in what situations the acquire() and acquireUninterruptibly() must (or must not) be used, how they are different; and also how to use them (code sample?).

Thank you very much.

Comment: acquire() is interruptable (I assume you know what means) and the other is not.  If you don't want an interrupt to stop the acquire() use the later, if you code can handle interrupts, use the former.

Comment: Peter, You said "...If you don't want an interrupt to stop the acquire() use the later..". So, will the acquired semaphored ever be useful when the thread itself got interrupted?

Comment: The semaphore is useful in either case.  The interrupt just changes the path the code takes.

Comment: "Interrupt" means whatever you want it to mean (unless the interrupt happens when you're in a library call, in which case, it means whatever you _and_ the library author want it to mean.)  Most of the time, developers want "interrupt" to mean, "shut everything down cleanly."  If you care about interrupts at all, then it's not likely that you're going to want any of your threads to ignore them.

Answer (score 9):

`acquire()` is interruptible. That means if a thread A is calling `acquire()` on a semaphore, and thread B interrupts threads A by calling `interrupt()`, then an `InterruptedException` will be thrown on thread A.

On the other hand `acquireUninterruptibly()` is not interruptible. That means if a thread A is calling `acquireUninterruptibly()` on a semaphore, and thread B interrupts threads A by calling `interrupt()`, then no `InterruptedException` will be thrown on thread A, just that thread A will have its interrupted status set after `acquireUninterruptibly()` returns.

Answer (score 4):

As per documentation :

Both methods acquires permit from Semaphore and blocking until one is available.
But acquire() method get interrupted that means it is blocking until the thread get interuppted and it throws Interrupted exception (which is checked one).

But acquireUninterruptibly() has not effect when thread gets interrupted , it maintains the block state until it get permit from semaphore.

Source : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquireUninterruptibly()

Answer (score 3):

Even though previous answers are technically correct i'd like to point out the following:

- If you are using `Semaphore` for transaction coordination between threads you may want to use `acquireUninterruptibly()` to complete you transaction ad clean exit your process when the transaction (somehow) cleanly finish by testing thread interrupted state (you will know that the thread may have been interrupted after the call).
- If you can handle `InterruptedException` and immediately exit transaction without the need of any further operation you can use `acquire()`.

Think you are waiting for a shared resource (a counter for example) to complete your transaction, if using `acquire()` and ignoring the exception you may get the wrong resource state (a non unique counter in this case), so you may still want to wait for the resource and check later what to do based on the thread state. If, for example, you are doing a batch of transactions you may want to complete the current one and skip the subsequents.